# String замена символа. Java

Tags: java, строки

Добрый день как можно заменить символ в String пробовал так:

```
for(int i=0;i<buffer_text.length();i++)
                    if (buffer_text.substring(i) == "+") {
                        buffer_text.substring(i)="-";
                    }
}
```

Ругается, еще пробовал создать еще один стринг и туда перезаписывать с изменениями

```
buffer_text_2+="+",buffer_text_2+=buffer_text.toString();
```

но не получается. Подскажите как решать мою проблему?

Comment: `buffer_text = buffer_text.replaceAll("+", "-");`

Comment: Оу это он во всей строки будет менять символы на противоположный. Он ругается на "+"

Comment: `buffer_text.replaceAll("\\+", "-");` в случае с +неудачный пример, его надо экранировать

Comment: а чем replace отличается от replaceAll. И спасибо большое помогло очень

Comment: они делают одно и то же, но у них разные типы аргументов и они по разному интерпретируются

Comment: А можно ли не менять все символы а только с определенным индексом?

Comment: То есть в строке имеется +2+2+2+2+2+2 и только допустим заменить 0 и 2 по индексу?

Comment: есть еще `replaceFirst`